# Autocomplete the data from a remote source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am currently using the jQuery UI autocomplete widget, pulling the data from a remote source.
My problem here is, I used to have only New York data needed preloaded.
But now, I added new cities; Boston and Los Angeles.
So I need the index.asp?DESTINATION= be newyork or boston or los angeles based on what the user will type so that the right data will load.
How should I modify it?

BTW, I already tried changing it to; `url: "index.asp?DESTINATION=" + $("#location").val(),`

Thank you!

Comment: In what variable is what the user 'typed' stored?

Comment: Wait, you would like to detect if the word "New York" is in what the user typed and use the autocorrect accordingly? Why not handle this on the server-side?

Comment: ok so you confused me too.
I am not doing anything like that, when user types n, new york or all other places will need to be listed, I just redirect to new york for simplicity before.

Comment: Actually thats what I tried first even before `$("#location").val()` but it did not work. I just tried it again, and same result.

Comment: You have to remember _this_ somewhere because it changes in the inner callback :/

Comment: What do you mean by "remember this"?

Comment: use `DESTINATION=` + request.term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Whitaker answered it in the comments.

`DESTINATION= + request.term`